# nginx installed successfully but cannot start

Tags: nginx, homebrew

I use homebrew to install nginx. However, when I start nginx, it prompts:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libpcre.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/nginx
  Reason: Incompatible library version: nginx requires version 4.0.0 or later, but libpcre.1.dylib provides version 2.0.0
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What about upgrading your `libpcre`?

Comment: @n1xx1 May I know how to do that?

Comment: @n1xx1 I ran `brew upgrade pcre`, and it is already the latest pcre-8.35

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I don't know what causes the problem. I checked my pcre, and it was in latest version. Without option I just uninstall it and reinstall it again...Then it works...

Answer (score 15):

I had this same problem, try running this:

`brew unlink pcre && brew link pcre`

In my case, this was the output:

`Unlinking /usr/local/Cellar/pcre/8.35... 5 symlinks removed
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/pcre/8.35... 133 symlinks created`

Comment: Got the same issue when trying to run React Native. Fixed by unlink and then force link: **`brew unlink pcre && brew link --overwrite pcre`**

Comment: If this doesn't fix the problem or the command fails you should try: `brew doctor` and follow the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Only thing that fixed it for me was reinstalling everything in brew.

https://gist.github.com/nmccready/adfae27c498e0795767f

Answer (score 0):

I run the following and it sorted the issue for me

`brew update && brew upgrade && brew rm extempore && brew install extempore`

Answer (score -1):

If you get any problem in nginx then you can debug using this command:

nginx -t

after running this command you will get error message including filename and line number where the problem is